# magento search order by relevance

Tags: search, magento, relevance

I have the following code:

`$collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/layer')->getProductCollection();`

I've tried

`$collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/layer')->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('relevance', 'desc')`

But it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this related answer: [Magento Search 'relevance' Value is Always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117162/magento-search-relevance-value-is-always-0/9184411#9184411)

It gives some insight into the relevance value of search results.